# Probability that exactly $3$ compartments have a passenger: what's wrong with my solution, how was the textbook answer obtained?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Exercise:
train car has $9$ compartments, each compartment has $4$ beds. There are $7$ passengers in the car. Find the probability that exactly $3$ compartments have a passenger.

My solution:
size of the event space is $C_{36}^{7}=\frac{36!}{7! \ 29!}.$ There are three ways for three compartments to be occupied: $7=1+2+4=1+3+3=2+2+3:$ one person in a compartment, two people in an other compartment, four people in yet another compartment, and the same for the next two decompositions of $7$.

Let's look at the first decomposition: the first person can choose any of the nine compartments, and any of the for four beds: $9\cdot4.$ The pair can choose out of eight remaining compartments, and a combination is needed to see in how many ways they can choose the beds: $8 \cdot C_{4}^{2}$. For the four people: $7\cdot 4$. Combining, we get $9\cdot4\cdot8\cdot C_4^2 \cdot7\cdot3$.

We do the same for the remaining two decompositions of $7$, and the answer is:
$$
\frac{9\cdot4\cdot8\cdot C_4^2 \cdot7\cdot 4 + 9\cdot 4 \cdot 8\cdot 4 \cdot 7\cdot 4 + \ 9\cdot C_4^2 \cdot 8\cdot C_4^2 \cdot 7\cdot 4}{C_{36}^7} = \frac{532}{28 985}.
$$

Textbook answer:
$$
\frac{C_9^3C_12^7 - C_9^2 C_8^1}{C_{36}^7} = \frac{46}{5797}.
$$

How did they get the textbook answer?
What is wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "The pair can choose out of eight remaining compartments, and a combination is needed to see in how many ways they can choose the beds: $8⋅C^2_4$. For the three people: 7⋅4"

You mean ".... for the *four* people". It's 1+2+4, not 1+2+3.

Also, for the combination 1+3+3, you need to break it down this way:

- The solo passenger can pick any of the 9 compartments, and any of the 4 beds, that's $9\times 4$
- The first trio can choose any of the 8 compartments, and there are 4 ways to pick their beds.
- The second trio can choose any of the 7 compartments, and there are 4 ways to pick their beds.
- But this double-counts the combinations, since there's no difference between (for example) "the first trio picks compartment A and the second picks Z" and "the first trio picks compartment Z and the second picks A", so you need to divide by $2!$

Alternatively,

- The solo passenger can pick any of the 9 compartments, and any of the 4 beds, that's $9\times 4$
- There are $C^2_8$ ways to choose two compartments for the two trios, and then $4\times 4$ ways for them to choose their beds.

As an aside: the more standard notation for (say) $C^4_{52}$ is ${}^{52}C_4$

You've similarly overcounted the 3+2+2's.

As an aside, the textbook answer seems to approach the problem like so:

Let's pick 3 cabins for them: there's ${}^9C_3$ ways to do that. Then let's pick beds for them out of the 12 beds: there's ${}^{12}C_7$ ways to do that.

Unfortunately, some of those combinations have everyone packed into just two (or maybe fewer) cabins, so we need to subtract those combinations.

Let's pick 2 cabins: there's ${}^9C_2$ ways to do that. Then let's pick beds: there's ${}^8C_7$ ways to do that.

So the number of ways to pack them into exactly 3 cabins is ${}^9C_3\times{}^{12}C_7-{}^9C_2\times{}^{8}C_7$.

Comment: Clear and helpful. Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, (a) I feel a little uneasy about the textbook's method, but can't put my finger on why (b) the two methods are giving different answers, and (c) I wrote a program to literally go through all possible combinations, and I get:
* 288 ways they can be in 2 cabins
* 64512 ways they can be in 3,
* 1048320, 3548160, 3096576 and 589824 ways they can be in 4, 5, 6 and 7 cabins

for a total of 8347680 = 36 choose 7 ways they can choose the beds.

Comment: If you want to argue with the teacher / textbook author, solve the case where there are 2 people, the train has 3 cabins with 2 beds each. And we want the number of combinations where there are 2 occupied cabins.

Your method gives 12. The textbook's method gives 15, which is nonsense, since there are only 15 ways to allocate 2 people to 6 beds. Literally drawing pictures of all the combinations gives 12.

Comment: I know what's wrong with the textbook's method now.

When they say "choose 3 cabins, and distribute the people amongst the 7 beds" they're thinking that gives "how many ways to have the 7 people in 3 or fewer cabins". So they then subtract the number of ways to "choose 2 cabins, and distribute the people amongst the 7 beds". 

But their method massively overcounts some combinations: eg, if I choose cabins A,B,C, and sleep the people in A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2,B3, I'll end up counting that combo again when I choose cabins A,B,D, and then A,B,E, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The question is very vague as to which entities are identical and which are distinct, and as Michael Hartly has pointed out in comments, the text book computations, too, are awry.

The best clue we get is from $^{36}C_7$ in the denominator which means that the matching numerator must be the number of ways that $7$ distinct berths have been occupied in exactly $3$ distinct compartments.

I am  giving the simplest  way to compute the numerator combinatorially, which Michael Hartley has  worked out through a program.

The three compartments can be chosen in $^9C3$ ways, and  there are three *patterns* of possible berth allotments, $4-2-1$ with $6$ permutations, $3-3-1$ with $3$ permutations and $3-2-2$, again with $3$ permutations.

Thus the required # of ways

$= \small{{}^9C_3\left({}^4C_4\cdot{}^4C_2\cdot{}^4c_1\cdot6 + {}^4C_3\cdot{}^4C_3\cdot{}^4C_1\cdot3 + {}^4C3\cdot{}^4C_2\cdot{}^4C_2\cdot3\right)} = 64512$

and $Pr = \dfrac{64512}{{}^{36}C_7} =\dfrac{224}{28985}$